# Is there a box with a slash?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

In my current project, I'm using the boxed versions of certain operations. The `amsmath` package provides convenient `\boxtimes` and `\boxplus` operators for this, which are the same size as `\square`.

However, I haven't been able to find a box with a slash (i.e. set-minus symbol). Is there a straightforward way I could make one, e.g. by somehow removing one of the lines from `\boxtimes`, or overlaying `\square` with an equally-sized slash symbol? The straightforward `\not\square` looks rather dreadful: [image]. `\cancel\square` looks somewhat better, but the line still extends beyond the edges of the square: [image].

Comment: `\boxslash` from [`stmaryrd`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd)...

Comment: @Werner That `\boxslash` is excellent but unfortunately not the same size and position as `\square`, `\boxtimes`, and `\boxplus`.

Comment: That can easily be changed using a `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` and placed in a new command of your choice.

Answer (score 7):

You can use tikz to make your own:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \newlength\squareheight
  \setlength\squareheight{6.75pt}
  \newcommand\squareslash{\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\squareheight,\squareheight);\draw(0,0) -- (\squareheight,\squareheight)}}
\begin{document}
  \[ A \squareslash B \]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can then get proper spacing using `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \newlength\squareheight
  \setlength\squareheight{6.75pt}
  \newcommand\squareslash{\tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\squareheight,\squareheight);\draw(0,0) -- (\squareheight,\squareheight)}}
  \DeclareMathOperator\squarediv{\squareslash}
\begin{document}
  \[ A \squarediv B \]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]